# When touch Input fields In HTML page, keybord footer buttons coming

Tags: html, ios, objective-c, iphone, cordova

Am using `cordova` 3.9.2 version, In `html` page I have added fixed type of  footer buttons
when user touch the input fields.. `keyboard` is coming up at that time footer button is coming up of the keyboard
 pls let know how to resolve this problem

Comment: That is the typical behavior of webviews. If you want to change this, you have to use a keyboard plugin and interaction, when the keyboard comes up.